# Cakephp php MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a working foreach loop in my **view**:

```
<? foreach($words as $word): ?>
        <td><?= $word['Word']['category'] ?></td>
<? endforeach; ?>
```

Function in my **Controller**:

```
public function index()
{
     $this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'conditions' => array('Word.role' => CakeSession::read("Auth.User.username")),
    'limit' => 100
);
$data = $this->Paginator->paginate('Word');
$this->set('words', $data);
}
```

The `foreach` shows all categories, but I want to show in my list only unique categories. How do you achieve this?

Comment: you may use [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html) in your query or find in case of cakePHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how you want to actually achieve this. If you are only using your `$words` array for unique categories then it would be best to remove duplicates when retrieving the data from the database. So something like this:-

```
$words = $this->Word->find('all', ['group' => 'category']);
```

Alternatively, if you need the full `$words` array for other purposes you can extract the categories from the array using [`Hash::extract()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html#Hash::extract) and then use [PHP's `array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) method to remove the duplicates just for your loop:-

```
$categories = Hash::extract($words, '{n}.Word.category');
$uniqueCategories = array_unique($categories);
foreach ($uniqueCategories as $category) {
    echo '<td>' . $category . '</td>';
}
```

Comment: If I use the first way - unexpected '['

Comment: I did try put it in Controller and also index - view - nothing

Comment: @andrzej sounds like you're using an old version of PHP. The square brackets are a shortcut for `array()`. Try using `$this->Word->find('all', array('group' => 'category'));` instead.

Comment: I tried this way, but nothing happens:
echo: category, category, category, category1, category1....

Comment: I modified function and now this work but not as it should be.
Must only 'echo' or 'print' unique category.
I think you need to change something in foreach.